# Qt - QCustomPlot painting graph

Tags: qt, graph, qcustomplot

I have a problem with drawing the graph in QCustomPlot library. I would like to draw a logarithm graph but I use drawing on the interval <-3;3>. Because logarithm is not defined from -3 to 0, I tried to do nothing while drawing on this interval.

I have this code:

```
QVector<double> x(10001), y(10001);
QVector<double> x1(10001), y1(10001);

double t=-3; //cas
double inkrement = 0.0006;
for (int i=0; i<10001; i++)//kvadraticka funkcia
{
  x[i] = t;
  y[i] = (-1)*t*t-2;
  t+=inkrement;
}

int g=0;
for(double l=-3;l<3; l+=inkrement) {
   if(l<=0.0) continue;
   else {
   //QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("note"), tr("l=%1\n").arg(l), QMessageBox::Ok);
   x1[g] = l;
   y1[g] = log10(l)/log10(exp(1.0));
   //QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("note"), tr("x1=%1\ny1=%2").arg(x1[g]).arg(y1[g]), QMessageBox::Ok);
   //break;
   g++;
   }
}

customPlot->addGraph();
customPlot->graph(0)->setData(x, y);

customPlot->addGraph();
customPlot->graph(1)->setData(x1, y1);

customPlot->xAxis->setLabel("x");
customPlot->yAxis->setLabel("y");

customPlot->xAxis->setRange(-3, 3);
customPlot->yAxis->setRange(-10, 5);
customPlot->replot();
```

where x1 and y1 are QVectors... But the graph is like the first point is in [0,0]. So I have then a line that connects point [0,0] with the logarithm graph and I dont know why :( 
When I put l=0.0006 before the cycle, everything is OK. Can you help me with that please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you set count of x1 and y1 before this loop. QVector is initialized with zeros. So if you don't set any value for some items then `x1` and `y1` will contain zero values at their end.

You should use empty QVector's and add new values if g is OK:

```
QVector<double> x1, y1;
//...
x1 << l;
y1 << log10(l)/log10(exp(1.0));
```

`g` variable can be removed then. And I think it's better to remove `i` variable and use `for(double l = -3; l <= 3; l+=increment)` loop.

Comment: Thank you :) Operator << works perfectly (problem solved)... but I still do not understand why my code behaves as it behaves... This is complete code (when I uncomment message box, it says, that the l value is higher than 0, and also x1[g] is too)... I will edit the code above and replace it with complete code.